# When JavaMailSender sends message this error has appeared. Please any ideas?

Tags: java, spring

I got this error:

class com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html cannot be cast to class jakarta.activation.DataContentHandler.

How to fix it?

Why com.sun instead of Jakarta?

I tried to add jakarta.activation dependency but I got this error.

Comment: please more details otherwise become hard support you to find and solve the issue